# Google page translate in Chrome does not work in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, translation

I am in Kubuntu 22.04 and I have Chrome Version 122.0.6261.128 (Official Build) (64-bit) and the google page translation stopped working today.
I am getting the popup `This page couldn't be translated`
Was there any recent update that broke this?
I have tried with multiple sites/languages

Comment: This issue is not local Ubuntu, and is part of Google Chrome as a whole problem.  More specifically, it's an issue with the Google Translate framework (because it affects Firefox too).  I do not think this is answerable within the scope of Ask Ubuntu because it's been doing this since yesterday on all OSes and multiple different endpoints

Comment: @ThomasWard: You mean this also happens on Windows and Macs?

Comment: @ThomasWard: Has the issue already been reported?

Comment: @ThomasWard: I can't find googling mentioning that there is a global issue with Google Translate.

Comment: I checked on a couple of android devices and mac and I don't see an issue there

Comment: I don't think Google is going to publicly state something if it was a temporary outage or if their APIs were being glitchy.  But yes, it was misbehaving on multiple systems a couple days ago, and started working against last night.